# Vaadin Grid Detail doesn't show Image correctly

Tags: java, vaadin, vaadin-grid

I have a Problem with my Vaadin Grid.
Its a rather simple Grid that just shows some cars with name, model, ps, etc.
If you click on one of the rows, the grid detail opens, and shows a picture of the car.
If you click on the first row in the grid, the Image is cut of and you cant scroll.
But if you click around a bit, for example you click on the 6th row , then the Picture is fine.
Also then you can scroll and if you click on the first row, the image is now shown correctly.
Is this a mistake by me or is this a bug?

```
public FahrzeugView()
    {
        final Grid<Fahrzeug> grid = new Grid<>(Fahrzeug.class, false);
        grid.setWidthFull();
        grid.setHeight("800px");
        grid.addColumn(Fahrzeug::getId).setHeader("Id").setSortable(true);
        grid.addColumn(Fahrzeug::getMarke).setHeader("Marke").setSortable(true);
        grid.addColumn(Fahrzeug::getModell).setHeader("Modell").setSortable(true);
        grid.addColumn(Fahrzeug::getPs).setHeader("Ps").setSortable(true).setId("ps");

        grid.setItemDetailsRenderer(this.createFahrzeugDetailsRenderer());
        final List<Fahrzeug> fahrzeuge = Fahrzeug.setData();
        grid.setItems(fahrzeuge);

        this.add(grid);
    }

    private Renderer<Fahrzeug> createFahrzeugDetailsRenderer()
    {
        return new ComponentRenderer<>(FahrzeugDetailLayout::new,    
                FahrzeugDetailLayout::setFahrzeug);
    }
}
```

```
public class FahrzeugDetailLayout extends FormLayout
{
    private final Image image = new Image("", "");

    public FahrzeugDetailLayout()
    {   
        setResponsiveSteps(new ResponsiveStep("0", 1));
            setColspan(this.image, 1);
            this.add(this.image);
        
    }

    public void setFahrzeug(final Fahrzeug fahrzeug)
    {
        this.image.setAlt("Bild wird nicht angezeigt!");
        this.image.setSrc(fahrzeug.getUrl());

    }
}
```

I dont understand why it is only cut of when you first open the detail and not when you click around and click on it again.
I dont really know what to try to fix this, because i dont know what is causing it to happen.
I tryed google for it but this Problem is very specific.

Thankfull for all the help!

Comment: Can you please add a prinscreen of what's expected and how it is shown wrong?

Comment: The issue is most likely that the image doesn't have an explicit size, so the renderer sizes itself without considering the picture. The browser already has the image the next time you open it, so the sizing is correct. Try defining the size of the image and see if that helps.

Comment: @MarcusHellberg seems like that solved the Problem! I added height and width to the pictures and now they get rendered properly, thanks!